# FTC in Integral Equation

Tags: calculus, proof-writing

I am working on the following exercise (Source is unknown, unfortunately):

> Find all continuous, non-negative functions $f:\Bbb{R}\to\Bbb{R}$ satisfying 
>   $$\int_0^xf(t)dt=(f(x))^\alpha +C$$
>   for some constant $C\neq 0$ and $\alpha >1$.

**Here is my attempt:**
Because of FTC, we know that $(f(x))^\alpha$ is a differentiable function (thus continuous), and because the composition of two continuous is also continuous, $f$ is continuous. Applying FTC we have that 
\begin{align*}
\frac{d}{dx}\int_0^xf(t)dt & = \frac{d}{dx}\Big[(f(x))^\alpha+C\Big]
\\ f(x) & =\alpha f(x)^{\alpha-1}f'(x)
\\ f(x)(\alpha f(x)^{\alpha-2}f'(x)-1) & = 0
\end{align*}
so $f(x)=0$ or $f'(x)=\alpha f(x)^{2-\alpha}$. 
Now, because this equation is in the form $y'+p(t)y=0$, we can probably do something with integrating factors and solve this D.E. *However*, I don't want to use any differential equation knowledge to solve this. How can I proceed?

Comment: I don't understand the grammar in your penultimate sentence. Are you saying you don't want to use *any* differential equation knowledge to solve this? Your stated form for the equation is wrong anyway; I recommend the Ansatz $g=f^\beta$, choosing $\beta$ so $g^\prime$ is $g$-independent.

Comment: But you **already used some differential equation** to solve: the very first step !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\frac{df}{dx}=\alpha f^{2-\alpha}$. By separating variables, we get $f^{\alpha-2}df=\alpha dx$. By integrating both sides, we have $\frac{1}{\alpha-1}f^{\alpha-1}=\alpha x+C$. Therefore, $f(x)=(\alpha(\alpha-1)x+C)^{\frac{1}{\alpha-1}}$ if $\alpha\neq1$. When $\alpha=1$ then $\frac{df}{f}=dx$. Therefore we have $ln f=x+C$. Hence $f(x)=Ce^{x}$.

Comment: If you evaluate the given relation at $x=0$, you can see that the given answer is probably not correct.